# Rails where clause to select by specific attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following query:

I have the following model:

```
2.1.5 :025 > OnlineCourseRegistration.last
 => #<OnlineCourseRegistration id: 14392, cart_id: 15177, user_id: 7133, course_class_id: 681, created_at: "2017-10-29 23:28:45", updated_at: "2017-10-30 20:18:53", exam_attempts: 0, exam_completed_at: nil, evaluation_completed_at: nil, status: "Active", score: "", add_extension: false, retest_cart_id: nil, retest_purchased_at: nil>
```

...and I am running this query:

```
registrations = OnlineCourseRegistration.where(course_class_id: 123).where(status: "Completed").where("score >= ?", 80)
```

It is possible that more than one record for the same user_id can be returned. If this is the case I would like to only return the last record...or the record with the latest :exam_completed_at date for that user.

For context here is the entire loop:

```
registrations = OnlineCourseRegistration.where(course_class_id: 123).where(status: "Completed").where("score >= ?", 80)
          if !registrations.empty?
            registrations.each do |b|
              email_recipients << b
          end
```

I build up the email_recipients array, then hand that off to a mailer. The issue I am having is that if the user gets returned twice, then they are getting two emails. I only want them to get a single email, so I would like on the the last record returned (or the record with the most recent exam_completed_at date.

Comment: You can either append `order(exam_completed_at: :desc).select('distinct on (email) name')` or just call `.uniq` on your email's array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
registrations = OnlineCourseRegistration.where(course_class_id: 842).where(status: "Completed").where("score >= ?", 80).order(exam_completed_at: :desc)
```

Note I added an order clause above, then...

```
registrations = registrations.uniq_by {|u| u.user_id}
```

I am unsure if uniq_by removes the first or last record, but this in combination with the additional order clause seems to do the trick.